# delay in javascript function attribute setter

Tags: javascript

we are calling a javascript function on click of a button and disabling that button at the first line of that function. (we need to disable that button so that user does not press the same button multiple times)

example code is as under:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary DialogSaveBtn" onclick="SavePatientExamination();">Save changes</button>

    function SavePatientMedicine()
{
    $(".DialogSaveBtn").attr("disabled", "disabled");

    var patId =  $("#PatId").val();
    var appId = $("#PatAppId").val();
    var visitNo = $("#PatVisitNo").val();

    var valid = true;
    var data = new Array();
    var tablecount = 0;
    $("#MedListTbl .DataRow").each(function () {
        debugger;
        if ($(this).find(".MedDays").val() == "" || $(this).find(".MedDays").val() <= 0 ||parseInt($(this).find(".MedDays").val())!= parseFloat($(this).find(".MedDays").val()))
        {
            alert("please enter valid 'Days' for medicines.");
            valid = false;
            return false;
        }
        tablecount = tablecount + 1;
        var row = {
            "iPMID": $(this).find(".RecId").val(),
            "PatId": patId,
            "AppId": appId,
            "MedicineId": $(this).find(".MedId").val(),

        };

        data.push(row);
    });
    if (tablecount > 0 && valid) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("SavePatientMedicine","OPD")',
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json;',
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            success: function (msg) {
                if (msg == true) {
                    toastr.success('Record Added Successfully', 'Medicine');
                    var appId = $("#PatAppId").val();

                    $('#OPDMedDialog').modal('hide');
                    $(".DialogSaveBtn").removeAttr("disabled");
                } else {
                    alert("Unable to save data");
                    $(".DialogSaveBtn").removeAttr("disabled");
                }
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("an error occured while saving data");
                $(".DialogSaveBtn").removeAttr("disabled");
            }
        });
    }
    else {
      //  $(".DialogSaveBtn").removeAttr("disabled");
    }

}
```

the issue we are facing is that if a user simultaneously clicks the button, the function is called twice before the button is actually disabled..

any help appreciated..

Comment: The button executes `SavePatientExamination` while you post the code for `SavePatientMedicine`.

Comment: Is the work asynchronous?

Comment: my apologies, actually there are multiple buttons like this..
the actual line is :
`<button class="btn btn-primary DialogSaveBtn" onclick="SavePatientMedicine();">Save changes</button>`

Comment: @AbdulAli I already thought so but I want to exclude anything simple :)

Comment: @JamesThorpe there is an ajax call inside that function.. but shouldnt the button be disabled as the first line of function is for that

Comment: Yes, it will be disabled.  However, is the removing of the disabled attribute inside or outside the async bit?  I'm guessing outside...

Comment: Since you are using ajax call. use that removeAttr("disabled") inside the success or failure method of the ajax call

Comment: In this example, you can only click the button once. Is that what you mean? https://jsfiddle.net/w5gv7guf/

Comment: @Pimskie the aim is to restrict the user to a single click until a success call  but currently that is not happening ..

Comment: I guess it is cause by the async work you do in between. DOM is not updated before the ajax call finishes. So you do not see it being disable/enable.

Comment: @PierreC. any suggestions ? :)
have also moved the removeattr code inside the success and error

Comment: In that case, make sure the success callback of your ajax call is executed and place the `$(".DialogSaveBtn").removeAttr("disabled");` in there. Or provide more code so we can see what's going on

Comment: Yes the Ajax call is important indeed. One hack I found on internet is to wrap the ajax call in a `setTimeout`. Setting a 20ms delay should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

You're not preventing the default behaviour of the button so even though you've set the disabled attr the button continues with its normal behaviour.

In this example I've added an event listener (rather than use an inline onclick attribute) and prevent the buttons default behaviour. Then I'm setting the disabled *property* (not attribute). Check your browser's console to see the console.log of "clicked" being fired only once even if you double click.

```js
$(function(){
  $(".DialogSaveBtn").on("click",SavePatientMedicine);
  
    function SavePatientMedicine(e){
        //prevent the normal button behaviour
        e.preventDefault();
        //set disabled property (not attr)
        $(".DialogSaveBtn").prop("disabled", true);
        //...
        console.log("clicked");
    }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-primary DialogSaveBtn">Save changes</button>
```

**UPDATE**:

To leave the inline event in place (as requested in your comment) simply pass the `event` into the function:

```js
  
    function SavePatientMedicine(e){
        //prevent the normal button behaviour
        e.preventDefault();
        //set disabled property (not attr)
        $(".DialogSaveBtn").prop("disabled", true);
        //...
        console.log("clicked");
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-primary DialogSaveBtn" onclick="SavePatientMedicine(event)">Save changes</button>
```

Comment: thank you for the answer , just one basic question .. if we have called the function like so: `<input .. onclick='function()'/>`  then how can we use the e.preventDefault.

Comment: the reason we wish to avoid changing to event listeners is that there are around 10-12 buttons like this and changing all of them may not be straightforward :)

Comment: @AbdulAli Simply pass the `event` object. See my update.

Answer (score 0):

```
function SavePatientMedicine() {
  $(".DialogSaveBtn").attr("disabled", "disabled");

  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "your url",
    dataType: "json",
    success:function(data) {
      $(".DialogSaveBtn").removeAttr("disabled");
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
      $(".DialogSaveBtn").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
  });

}
```

This should be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('.myButton').bind('dblclick',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
})
```

Comment: I think the double click is a symptom of the button not being disabled at the right time. Disabling the button onClick does prevent double click.

Comment: Yes but, the symptom rises because the user does not allow the function to be triggered on the first click. In the code above, it will check for more than one click and prevent default.